# Content on first tab is gone after adding another tab C# winforms

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, user-interface

I have to write a paint application with multiple tabs. The application consists of a button that adds tabs and tab control (each tab has one `PictureBox`). When I click on button, a new tab with a `PictureBox` is added to `TabControl`. The problem occurs when I add a new tab and add it to `TabControl`: the drawings on the selected tab are gone. I tried to debug it, but I cannot reach specific line of code, which makes the content of `PictureBox` disappear (the content of selected tab disappears when I call `tabControl.Controls.Add(tab);`.

Below is the code of the event handler:

```
   private void AddTabButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        TabPage tab = new TabPage();
        tab.Name = DateTime.Now.Subtract(DateTime.MinValue.AddYears(1969)).TotalMilliseconds.ToString();
        tab.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString();
        PictureBox p = new PictureBox();
        p.ClientSize = new Size(613, 244);
        p.BackColor = Color.White;
        p.MouseDown += (a, b) =>
        {
            var checkedFigureButton = FigurePanel.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
            var checkedColorButton = ColorPanel.Controls.OfType<RadioButton>().FirstOrDefault(r => r.Checked);
            if (checkedColorButton.Text != null)
            {
                System.Drawing.Color color;
                switch (checkedColorButton.Text)
                {
                    case "Red":
                        color = Color.Red;
                        break;
                    case "Green":
                        color = Color.Green;
                        break;
                    case "Blue":
                        color = Color.Blue;
                        break;
                    default:
                        color = Color.Black;
                        break;
                }
                switch (checkedFigureButton.Text)
                {
                    case "Casual":
                        figure = new Casual(this.tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0].CreateGraphics(), color, b.X, b.Y);
                        break;
                    case "Line":
                        figure = new Line(this.tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0].CreateGraphics(), color, b.X, b.Y, b.X, b.Y);
                        break;
                    case "Rectangle":
                        figure = new Rectangle(this.tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0].CreateGraphics(), color, b.X, b.Y, b.X, b.Y);
                        break;
                    default:
                        break;
                }
                figure.UpdateCurrentPosition(b.X, b.Y);
            }
        };
        p.MouseUp += (a, b) =>
        {
            figure.Release((PictureBox)this.tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0]);
            figure = null;
        };
        p.MouseMove += (a, b) =>
        {
            if (figure != null)
            {
                figure.Move(b, (PictureBox)this.tabControl.SelectedTab.Controls[0]);
            }
        };
        tab.Controls.Add(p);
        tabControl.Controls.Add(tab); // after this function is being called (and exit from the event) the content of PictureBox on selected tab disappears
    }
```

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint in mouseup event. Looks like that might be getting hit where are clearing the content. Or write to debug in that event.

Comment: Your mistake is almost certainly the use of `CreateGraphics()` in the constructor of `figure`.  Use the `Paint()` event of the PictureBox instead. In that event, you are given a graphics to draw to in the parameters via `e.Graphics`.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an [Interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/interfaces/) called `Figure` that all of your shapes Implement.  That interface would need a `Draw()` method that receives a Graphics to draw on:

```
public interface Figure
{
    void Draw(Graphics G);
}
```

Here's an example of the Line class implementing interface Figure:

```
public class Line : Figure
{
    public void Draw(Graphics G)
    {
        // ... draw with "G" in here ...
    }
}
```

Repeat for each type of shape, obviously customizing the draw method accordingly.

Now, in the MouseDown event of your PictureBox where you create "figure", store a reference to "figure" in the `Tag()` property of the PB.  You can cast your "a" parameter to type Control to achieve this:

```
p.MouseDown += (a, b) =>
{
    // ... existing code that creates "figure" ...
    Control ctl = (Control)a;
    ctl.Tag = figure;
};
```

Then, in the [Paint()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.paint?view=netframework-4.8) event of your PictureBox, you can cast the `Tag()` property to type `Figure` and call `Draw()`.  Again, you'd first cast the "a" parameter to type Control or PictureBox.  Pass in the Graphics supplied to you via the ["b" parameter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.painteventargs?view=netframework-4.8):

```
p.Paint += (a, b) =>
{
    Control ctl = (Control)a;
    Figure figure = (Figure)ctl.Tag;
    figure.Draw(b.Graphics);
};
```